# Jquery .find() with ^= selector - too many results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jQuery.find()` to find the elements under an id. But I have a issue.

Code:

```
$('#myId').children().find('input[id^=course_' + subId + ']').attr('checked', false);
```

I have elements which have subId as `sel_1` and `sel_11` and `sel_12`. How can i get just sel_1 as the above is giving all three results?

Comment: `$('#course_sel_1').prop('checked', false);`

Comment: Don't think you need `.children()`.  Further, why not use `id="course_sel_1"` instead of `id^="course_sel_1"`, which is a "starts with" selector?

Comment: As j08691 pointed out, if you want just one result, don't perform an attribute pattern matching selector.  Especially with ids.

Comment: Given that you're looking for an id, and given that each id should be unique in the document, the proper solution seems to be `$('#course_' + subId).attr('checked', false)`

Comment: Why are you using the `^=` ? Did you copy it from somewhere without knowing what it does?

Answer (score -1):

**Updated**

As the comments suggested the selector could be improved.
This was the problem `id^=course`, you are telling to jquery to get all elements that start with `course_' + subId`. This line solves the problem:

```
$('input[id=course_' + subId + ']').attr('checked', false);
```

Comment: Why `.children()`? Seems unnecessary (worth pointing out to OP if you're going to provide a full answer).

Comment: And since IDs **must** be unique, what's the point of that long, convoluted selector? Also, since jquery 1.6 you should use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` with `checked`

Comment: This answer also ignores that an `id` is supposed to be unique

Comment: Because maybe he is trying to get the childrens of ('#myId') that match with id="course_sel_1".  I know you are asking because as id is unique, but if we think that this childs could be generate from somewhere else, this childs could be belong to a different parent in some point.

Answer (score -5):

```
$('#myId')
.find('input[id^=course_' + subId + ']')
.prop('checked', false)
.first();
```

https://api.jquery.com/first/

But if you need `sel_1` precisely, then why not implement `id` attribute it.

```
$('#course_sel_1').prop('checked', false);
```

jQuery will precisely select that element.

If it is dynamically generated, then use find

```
$('#myId').find('#course_sel_1').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, what if `sel_11` is before `sel_1`?  Then you just get `sel_11`....

Comment: Wow, you guys are so fast. Loved it.